# How do I select data for a period of time say a month for plotting?

Tags: pandas, datetime, data-processing

I want to be able to visualise and analyse data for a specific period of time. The data is in different files so i read each file and appended them into an array. The data I have is in Julien date format so i used a function to convert it to datetime so that i am able to plot the data. However the function is now giving an error:

1. File "D:\DATA\TEC DATA\2018\amco\RES\CMN_append_df_stack_merge.py", line 162, in jd_to_date
       jd = jd + 0.5

   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
2. It was not giving this error before however the plot had lines crisscrossing everywhere which i suspect is because of the datetime not being formatted correctly.

Here is the code i used

```
*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Mar  9 17:51:41 2020

@author: user
"""

import glob as glob

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
"""
Functions for converting dates to/from JD and MJD. Assumes dates are historical
dates, including the transition from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian
calendar in 1582. No support for proleptic Gregorian/Julian calendars.
:Author: Matt Davis
:Website: http://github.com/jiffyclub
"""

import math
import datetime as dt

# Note: The Python datetime module assumes an infinitely valid Gregorian calendar.
#       The Gregorian calendar took effect after 10-15-1582 and the dates 10-05 through
#       10-14-1582 never occurred. Python datetime objects will produce incorrect
#       time deltas if one date is from before 10-15-1582.

def mjd_to_jd(mjd):
    """
    Convert Modified Julian Day to Julian Day.

    Parameters
    ----------
    mjd : float
        Modified Julian Day

    Returns
    -------
    jd : float
        Julian Day


    """
    return mjd + 2400000.5


def jd_to_mjd(jd):
    """
    Convert Julian Day to Modified Julian Day

    Parameters
    ----------
    jd : float
        Julian Day

    Returns
    -------
    mjd : float
        Modified Julian Day

    """
    return jd - 2400000.5


def date_to_jd(year,month,day):
    """
    Convert a date to Julian Day.

    Algorithm from 'Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet', 
        4th ed., Duffet-Smith and Zwart, 2011.

    Parameters
    ----------
    year : int
        Year as integer. Years preceding 1 A.D. should be 0 or negative.
        The year before 1 A.D. is 0, 10 B.C. is year -9.

    month : int
        Month as integer, Jan = 1, Feb. = 2, etc.

    day : float
        Day, may contain fractional part.

    Returns
    -------
    jd : float
        Julian Day

    Examples
    --------
    Convert 6 a.m., February 17, 1985 to Julian Day

    >>> date_to_jd(1985,2,17.25)
    2446113.75

    """
    if month == 1 or month == 2:
        yearp = year - 1
        monthp = month + 12
    else:
        yearp = year
        monthp = month

    # this checks where we are in relation to October 15, 1582, the beginning
    # of the Gregorian calendar.
    if ((year < 1582) or
        (year == 1582 and month < 10) or
        (year == 1582 and month == 10 and day < 15)):
        # before start of Gregorian calendar
        B = 0
    else:
        # after start of Gregorian calendar
        A = math.trunc(yearp / 100.)
        B = 2 - A + math.trunc(A / 4.)

    if yearp < 0:
        C = math.trunc((365.25 * yearp) - 0.75)
    else:
        C = math.trunc(365.25 * yearp)

    D = math.trunc(30.6001 * (monthp + 1))

    jd = B + C + D + day + 1720994.5

    return jd


def jd_to_date(jd):
    """
    Convert Julian Day to date.

    Algorithm from 'Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet', 
        4th ed., Duffet-Smith and Zwart, 2011.

    Parameters
    ----------
    jd : float
        Julian Day

    Returns
    -------
    year : int
        Year as integer. Years preceding 1 A.D. should be 0 or negative.
        The year before 1 A.D. is 0, 10 B.C. is year -9.

    month : int
        Month as integer, Jan = 1, Feb. = 2, etc.

    day : float
        Day, may contain fractional part.

    Examples
    --------
    Convert Julian Day 2446113.75 to year, month, and day.

    >>> jd_to_date(2446113.75)
    (1985, 2, 17.25)

    """
    jd = jd + 0.5

    F, I = math.modf(jd)
    I = int(I)

    A = math.trunc((I - 1867216.25)/36524.25)

    if I > 2299160:
        B = I + 1 + A - math.trunc(A / 4.)
    else:
        B = I

    C = B + 1524

    D = math.trunc((C - 122.1) / 365.25)

    E = math.trunc(365.25 * D)

    G = math.trunc((C - E) / 30.6001)

    day = C - E + F - math.trunc(30.6001 * G)

    if G < 13.5:
        month = G - 1
    else:
        month = G - 13

    if month > 2.5:
        year = D - 4716
    else:
        year = D - 4715

    return year, month, day


def hmsm_to_days(hour=0,min=0,sec=0,micro=0):
    """
    Convert hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds to fractional days.

    Parameters
    ----------
    hour : int, optional
        Hour number. Defaults to 0.

    min : int, optional
        Minute number. Defaults to 0.

    sec : int, optional
        Second number. Defaults to 0.

    micro : int, optional
        Microsecond number. Defaults to 0.

    Returns
    -------
    days : float
        Fractional days.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> hmsm_to_days(hour=6)
    0.25

    """
    days = sec + (micro / 1.e6)

    days = min + (days / 60.)

    days = hour + (days / 60.)

    return days / 24.


def days_to_hmsm(days):
    """
    Convert fractional days to hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds.
    Precision beyond microseconds is rounded to the nearest microsecond.

    Parameters
    ----------
    days : float
        A fractional number of days. Must be less than 1.

    Returns
    -------
    hour : int
        Hour number.

    min : int
        Minute number.

    sec : int
        Second number.

    micro : int
        Microsecond number.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If `days` is >= 1.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> days_to_hmsm(0.1)
    (2, 24, 0, 0)

    """
    hours = days * 24.
    hours, hour = math.modf(hours)

    mins = hours * 60.
    mins, min = math.modf(mins)

    secs = mins * 60.
    secs, sec = math.modf(secs)

    micro = round(secs * 1.e6)

    return int(hour), int(min), int(sec), int(micro)


def datetime_to_jd(date):
    """
    Convert a `datetime.datetime` object to Julian Day.

    Parameters
    ----------
    date : `datetime.datetime` instance

    Returns
    -------
    jd : float
        Julian day.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> d = datetime.datetime(1985,2,17,6)  
    >>> d
    datetime.datetime(1985, 2, 17, 6, 0)
    >>> jdutil.datetime_to_jd(d)
    2446113.75

    """
    days = date.day + hmsm_to_days(date.hour,date.minute,date.second,date.microsecond)

    return date_to_jd(date.year,date.month,days)


def jd_to_datetime(jd):
    """
    Convert a Julian Day to an `jdutil.datetime` object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    jd : float
        Julian day.

    Returns
    -------
    dt : `jdutil.datetime` object
        `jdutil.datetime` equivalent of Julian day.

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --------
    >>> jd_to_datetime(2446113.75)
    datetime(1985, 2, 17, 6, 0)

    """
    year, month, day = jd_to_date(jd)

    frac_days,day = math.modf(day)
    day = int(day)

    hour,min,sec,micro = days_to_hmsm(frac_days)

    return datetime(year,month,day,hour,min,sec,micro)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
#"""
#JULIEN DAY CONVERTOR 

def timedelta_to_days(td):
    """
    Convert a `datetime.timedelta` object to a total number of days.

    Parameters
    ----------
    td : `datetime.timedelta` instance

    Returns
    -------
    days : float
        Total number of days in the `datetime.timedelta` object.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> td = datetime.timedelta(4.5)
    >>> td
    datetime.timedelta(4, 43200)
    >>> timedelta_to_days(td)
    4.5

    """
    seconds_in_day = 24. * 3600.

    days = td.days + (td.seconds + (td.microseconds * 10.e6)) / seconds_in_day

    return days


"""
'Start of main Code---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
"""
#########

files = glob.glob('*.Cmn')
files = files[:3]
np_array_values = []
for file in files:
         df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\t", sep ='\t', skiprows = 5, names = ["Jdate" ,'Time' ,'PRN' ,'Az','Ele','Lat', 'Lon' ,'Stec', 'Vtec', 'S4'])
         #df.set_index('Jdatet')



         #Appending Each data frame to the Giant Array np-array_values then Stacking them

         np_array_values.append (df)
         merge_values = np.vstack(np_array_values) 
         #CONVERTING ARRAY BACK TO DATA FRAME
         TEC_data =pd.DataFrame(merge_values)

         Vtec = TEC_data.loc[:,7]
         jdate = TEC_data.loc[:,0]
         Time = TEC_data.loc[:,1]
         month_name = file[:-7]
         STATION_NAME = file[:4]

df.replace('-99.000', np.nan)

pos= np.where(jdate)[0]
pos1=np.where(Vtec[pos]<-20.0)[0]

Vtec[pos1]='nan'

fulldate = []

for i in jdate:
    a = jd_to_datetime(i)
    fulldate.append(a)


         #plt.show()
plt.plot(fulldate,  Vtec)
 #plt.xlim(0, 24)
 #plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 26, 2))
plt.ylabel('TECU')

plt.xlabel('Date')

#plt.grid(axis='both')

plt.title("Station : " + STATION_NAME.upper())t**
```

Here is a sample of the data. The columns are:
nknown_station, "E:\GPS DATA\rbmc2\2018\amco\amco3630.18o"

-4.87199    294.66602   75.87480

Jdatet       Time    PRN     Az  Ele     Lat     Lon     Stec    Vtec    S4
2458481.500000  -24.000000   1  198.34  23.37   -10.70  292.70  18.62   13.70   -99.000
2458481.500347  0.008333     1  198.21  23.53   -10.67  292.73  18.65   13.74   -99.000
2458481.500694  0.016667     1  198.07  23.69   -10.64  292.75  18.76   13.84   -99.000
2458481.501042  0.025000     1  197.94  23.85   -10.61  292.78  18.68   13.83   -99.000
2458481.501389  0.033333     1  197.81  24.01   -10.58  292.80  18.60   13.83   -99.000
2458481.501736  0.041667     1  197.68  24.17   -10.55  292.83  18.53   13.83   -99.000
2458481.502083  0.050000     1  197.54  24.33   -10.52  292.85  18.53   13.86   -99.000
2458481.502431  0.058333     1  197.41  24.49   -10.49  292.88  18.51   13.88   -99.000
2458481.502778  0.066667     1  197.28  24.65   -10.46  292.90  18.66   14.00   -99.000
2458481.503125  0.075000     1  197.15  24.81   -10.43  292.92  18.78   14.09   0.238
2458481.503472  0.083333     1  197.01  24.98   -10.40  292.95  18.55   14.01   -99.000
2458481.503819  0.091667     1  196.88  25.14   -10.37  292.97  18.39   13.96   -99.000
2458481.504167  0.100000     1  196.75  25.30   -10.34  292.99  18.33   13.97   -99.000
2458481.504514  0.108333     1  196.62  25.47   -10.31  293.02  18.20   13.94   -99.000
2458481.504861  0.116667     1  196.49  25.63   -10.28  293.04  17.61   13.67   -99.000
2458481.505208  0.125000     1  196.36  25.80   -10.25  293.06  16.74   13.25   -99.000
2458481.505556  0.133333     1  196.23  25.96   -10.22  293.09  16.06   12.92   -99.000
2458481.505903  0.141667     1  196.10  26.13   -10.19  293.11  15.46   12.64   -99.000
2458481.506250  0.150000     1  195.97  26.30   -10.16  293.13  14.77   12.31   -99.000
2458481.506597  0.158333     1  195.84  26.46   -10.13  293.15  14.42   12.15   0.127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the list containing the datetime object as an index to the Dataframe.
Apparently to recognise the dates you need to use plt.plot_date instead of using the usual plt.plot. Datetime index will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your variable `jd` is a string instead of a float. Can you show some sample data? This would probably explain why this is happening.

---

Some additional points about your code:

While looping over all files, you want to create one dataframe. This can be done easier:

```
dfMerged = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    dfTemp = pd.read_csv(...)
    dfMerged = dfMerged.append(dfTemp, ignore_index=True)
```

This would lead to the additional benefit that you can use your column headings like they are supposed to be used, e.g., `Vtec = dfMerged['Vtec']`.

Your `month_name` and `STATION_NAME` are overwritten in each iteration of the loop. If they are different for each file, you want to save them as a list or as a separate column in the dataframe, e.g., `dfTemp['Station'] = STATION_NAME`. Keep in mind to do this before you merge the dataframes.

Also, the `replace` can be substituted by adding `'-99.000'` to the `na_values` argument in `read_csv`.

Selecting your data can be done with pandas. `dfMerged.loc[(dfMerged['Jdate'].notna()) & (dfMerged['Vtec'] < -20), 'Vtec'] = pd.NA`.

Comment: Thanks i added a sample of the data

Comment: @LordHammer Can you format your data in a way to easily copy and paste it? At the moment it's all separated by spaces and there are no line breaks either. Also, a few lines are enough to test the code. Besides that, you expect `jdate` to be a float in the millions. However, your first column is at best your two-digit year or at worst a string of numbers like `18 302 52` depending on where the tabs are in the original data.

Comment: Well, your import is not working. `jd` is not a number, but actually the whole row. You import the data by defining `\t` as the column separator. However, there are no tabs in your files. Therefore, pandas populates only the first column. What do you expect for an input to `jd_to_date`? I cannot see you converting the year, day and seconds to a float anywhere.

Comment: I had the data mixed up that is the correct sample data i uploaded, my bad.

Comment: I copied your data into a txt file and used `pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1, names=['Jdate', 'Time', 'PRN', 'Az', 'Ele', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Stec', 'Vtec', 'S4'])`. I ran your code and no error occured. Are you sure your whole `Jdata` column is only floats?

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. It has a date in Julien format like so  
 "2.458122e+06"

Comment: The problem was importing datetime for the Typer Error  it was supposed to be from datetime import datetime but still the plot has lines crisscrossing the graph